# apply listStyle to Prompts.text() in bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-bots

I'm updating my question. I have requirement to subscribe the multiple items from list. 
I was searching on internet for the same but no luck and no option to select multiple option by using choice prompt with botframework nodejs SDK.

I guess if we use the prompt.text() its allow to accept the response entity as string may be it will help me to achieve my goal and also needed the **button look and feel** for the optionList.

Here is my Code

```
bot.dialog('/Subscriptions List', [
    function (session, args) {
        getSubscriptionsdemo(session);
    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.send(results.response);
        if(results.response.entity != '') { 
            session.send("You entered '%s'", results.response);
            session.beginDialog('/Confrim Subscribe');
        }
    }
]);

function getSubscriptionsdemo(session) {
    var body = [{"Name":"Computers"},{"Name":"Technology"},{"Name":"photography"},{"Name":"Cars"},{"Name":"Sports"}];
    var jsondata = (body);
    //var jsondata = parseJson(subscribeData);
    var subscribeArray = '';
    var indexVal =1;
    for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
        if (jsondata[i].Name != '' && jsondata[i].Name != undefined && jsondata[i].Name != null) {
            subscribeArray += indexVal+'. '+jsondata[i].Name+'\n';
        }
        indexVal++;
    }
    if(jsondata.length > 0) { 
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Select your subscriptions [ Multiple selectation seperate by comma (,) ]?\n\n"+subscribeArray);
    } else { 
        session.send('There is no subscriptions have been associated. You can use the back or top command.');
        session.beginDialog('/menu');
    }
}
```

### OR

Can we apply the listStyle to Prompts.text() in bot framework.

```
builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Cat|dog|mouse',{listStyle: builder.ListStyle.list});
```

Please guide me if Yes.

thanks

Comment: Any reason you are trying to use a text prompt instead of choice prompt for this?

Comment: You need to use a choice prompt for this!

Comment: @ Ezequiel Jadib As I required to select the multiple option from the list. I search for the choice prompt but no luck :(. So I was trying to find out the solution if it will work for the text prompt.

Comment: Updated my question @EzequielJadib

Comment: @EzequielJadib any change to accomplish my requirement or can it possible to use the css layout to my getSubscriptionsdemo function to display as like button. Please guide me.